# How to Calculate Sum and Average using while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

Am Creating a result Compiler and i want to calculate the Total, average and Grade of a student but whenever i try calculating the sum it ends giving me zero please help me.. Below is the Code i used:

```
<?php
require 'php/functions.php';

if (isset($_GET['student'])) {
     $student   =  $_GET['student'];
     $part      = explode(' ', $student);
     $lastname = $part[0];
     $firstname = $part[1];




    //selecting values from database;
    $query      =   "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `lastname` = '$lastname' AND `firstname` = '$firstname'";
    $result     =   mysql_query($query);
    $numrows    =   mysql_num_rows($result);

    $class      =   mysql_result($result, 0, 'class');
    $house      =   mysql_result($result, 0, 'house');
    $gender     =   mysql_result($result, 0, 'gender');
    $ad_no      =   mysql_result($result, 0, 'admission_no');



    if ($numrows == 1) {
        ?>
        <p>Lastname: <?php echo trim($lastname); ?></p>
        <p>Firstname: <?php echo trim($firstname); ?></p>
        <p>Class: <?php echo trim($class); ?></p>
        <p>House: <?php echo trim($house); ?></p>
        <p>Gender: <?php echo trim($gender); ?></p>
        <p>Admission Number: <?php echo trim($ad_no); ?></p>

        <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="9">
    <tr>
        <td>Subjects</td>
        <td>C.A</td>
        <td>M.T.E</td>
        <td>Exam</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Grade</td>
        <td>Remark</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <?php
     $query     =   "SELECT `name` FROM `senior_subject`";
     $result    =   mysql_query($query);


      while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<td>".$rows['name']."<br/></td>";

        ?>

    <td><input type="text"
    name = "<?php echo $rows['name'].'_ca'; ?>"
    placeholder = "<?php echo $rows['name']; ?> CA"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" 
    name = "<?php echo $rows['name'].'_mte'; ?>"
    placeholder = "<?php echo $rows['name']; ?> MTE"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" 
    name = "<?php echo $rows['name'].'_exam'; ?>"
    placeholder = "<?php echo $rows['name']; ?> EXAM"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled='disabled' name = "<?php echo $rows['name'].'_total'; ?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled='disabled' name = "<?php echo $rows['name'].'_grade'; ?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled='disabled' name = "<?php echo $rows['name'].'_remark'; ?>"/></td>



    </tr>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['compile'])) {
            $ca = $rows['name'].'_ca';
            $mte = $rows['name'].'_mte';
            $exam = $rows['name'].'_exam';
            $total = $rows['name'].'_total';
            $grade = $rows['name'].'_grade';
            $total = $rows['name'].'_remark';

            echo $ca + $mte + $exam;

        }
     }
     ?>
<input type="submit" value="Compile" name="compile"/>

</table>
</form>

        <?php

    } else {
        echo "Student Does Not Exists";
    }
} else {
    echo "You don't have Permission to access this page";
}
?>
```

Comment: Enter proper code what is $rows['name'] in all the rows

Comment: where are you really trying to calculate? and nice sql injection.

Comment: Everytime someone uses deprecated `mysql_*` functions a cute little kitty dies somewhere in the world.

Comment: I want to calculate the total @SanzeebAryal

Comment: i dont understand @RajkumarR

Comment: @Abdul please show your current output of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['compile'])) {
        $ca = $rows['name'].'_ca';
        $mte = $rows['name'].'_mte';
        $exam = $rows['name'].'_exam';
        $total = $rows['name'].'_total';
        $grade = $rows['name'].'_grade';
        $total = $rows['name'].'_remark';
        $total += $total;
}
```

And outside of the while loop in starting add $total = 0;

In ending echo $total;

Comment: Tnx Sir but it showed me blank after running your Code Instead to echo the total i don't know what have done wrong

Comment: Did you add the $total beginning of the while loop(outside)

Comment: Yes Sir i did it is giving me the value of Zero